# AngularJS - Calling Service Function From the Same Service

Tags: angularjs

I have the following service:

```
myApp.service('myService', function(){

    this.functionOne = function(){
         return true;
    };

    this.functionTwo = function(){
         // Call functionOne
    };

});
```

I would like to call `functionOne` from `functionTwo` without having to rewrite the way the service is written (in this case, returning an object with functions).

Is there a way to do this using the `this` format of providing functions?

Comment: `this.functionOne()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the safest is to just define a `_this` variable.

```
myApp.service('myService', function(){
   var _this = this;
   this.functionOne = function(){
        return true;
   };

   this.functionTwo = function(){
        var x = _this.functionOne();
   };
});
```

In this case the variable `_this` references the `myService` object that is created by AngularJS.

The problem here is that `this` is a JavaScript special variable that can be assigned values. It doesn't work like it does in other languages. So unless you know what the `this` variable will be at the time of the closure functions execution you should just use a variable you know is safe.

Comment: I've tried saving `this` to the service scope, but it seems that the context object changes when the service is used and I am not able to call functions using the saved object

Comment: `to the service scope`. I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify please.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
  var firstFn = function() {
    secondFn();
    //some code
  }

  var secondFn = function() {
     //additional code
  }

  return {
    firstFn: firstFn;
  }

})
```

This code exposes the firstFn to wherever this service gets called. When you call firstFn, it will also run secondFn. You can access firstFn using `myService.firstFn()` whenever you inject this service. Hope that helps.

Note: I've used a factory instead of a service. There's a subtle yet significant difference between the two. Long story short, a factory is a bit more flexible than a service with respect to what you can do with it.